# Initialize date variable and calculate age

Tags: swift, date

I have the following data structure in my project.
Basically I have two variables that I'm not able to set up:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Rosa: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let stagione: String
    let nomeGiocatore: String
    let cognomeGiocatore: String
    let nascitaGiocatore: Date
    let etàGiocatore: Int
    let ruoloGiocatore: String
    
    init(stagione: String, nomeGiocatore: String, cognomeGiocatore: String, nascitaGiocatore: Date, etàGiocatore: Int, ruoloGiocatore: String) {
        self.stagione = stagione
        self.nomeGiocatore = nomeGiocatore
        self.cognomeGiocatore = cognomeGiocatore
        self.nascitaGiocatore = nascitaGiocatore
        self.etàGiocatore = etàGiocatore
        self.ruoloGiocatore = ruoloGiocatore
        
        nascitaGiocatore.formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted)
    }
    
    static func testRosa() -> [Rosa] {
        [Rosa(stagione: "2023/2024", nomeGiocatore: "Matt", cognomeGiocatore: "Bar", nascitaGiocatore: 03/31/2000, etàGiocatore: 23, ruoloGiocatore: "Portiere")]
    }
}
```

I'd like to have "nascitaGiocatore" in the format "dd-MM-YYYY" and "etàGiocatore" as the difference between current year and "nascitaGiocatore" year.
But I'm completely stuck.

Comment: A Date doesn’t have a format, you can have a String or a date that can be formatted however you want. Date is actually a Double based on a reference date.

Comment: As an aside, `dd-MM-YYYY` is not correct. I think you likely intended `dd-MM-yyyy`. They are not the same thing. See https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a DateFormatter to parse the birth date string in the testRosa method. It should be something like below:

```
static func testRosa() -> [Rosa] {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let birthDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "31-03-2000")!
        
        let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
        let birthYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: birthDate)
        let age = currentYear - birthYear
        
        return [Rosa(stagione: "2023/2024", nomeGiocatore: "Matt", cognomeGiocatore: "Bar", nascitaGiocatore: birthDate, etàGiocatore: age, ruoloGiocatore: "Portiere")]
    }
```

Also you don't need to format 'nascitaGiocatore' at the **init** function. It seemed unnecessary. You can remove it.

Comment: Hi, it seems to work but the issue I have is that of course "nascitaGiocatore" is changing within the array. I need to express it in the function as part of the arrays. For example, I have the array for Matt Bar whose birthday was on 31-03-2000, but then I'd like to add other data with a different birthday date

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a "convenience initializer" that takes a date **String** in your expected format, and all the other parameters of your struct.

In swift a convenience initializer takes parameters other than the ones that your "designated" initializer takes, does the required conversions, and then calls the designated initializer. Read up on convenience initializers in Apple's Swift eBook if you're not familiar with them.

I'd suggest using a parameter label like "dateDDMMYYYYString" for your convenience initializer. That way it's self-documenting, and you could even later add another convenience init that took a date string in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice localized string representing the age (time between two different dates), you might use [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/):

```swift
private extension Rosa {
    static let ageFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

And then you can do things like:

```swift
extension Rosa {
    var age: String {
       Self.ageFormatter.string(from: birthday, to: .now) ?? "?"   // For US users, see “29 years”; For italian users, see “29 anni”
    }
}
```

This is a computed property that you can then use on your various instances, e.g.:

```swift
let rosa = Rosa(…)
print(rosa.age)
```

---

In terms of creating a `Date` object, there is no “date literal”. You have to convert from a `String` to a `Date`, yourself. E.g., if getting this from some [invariant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/#2528261) format (e.g., a web service, a database, etc., which always returns it using a Gregorian calendar, regardless of what the end users’ device is using), you might use [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/) with `yyyy-MM-dd` format (which eliminates ambiguity between day-month-year devices and month-day-year devices and is a more common convention, namely ISO8601 and RFC3339):

```swift
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = .withFullDate
// formatter.timeZone = .current                        // if you want GMT/UTC/Zulu, omit this; if you want it in your local timezone, uncomment this
guard let date = formatter.date(from: "2000-03-31") else { return }
print(date)
```

Or, if you really must use day-month-year format (even if user is in US where they use month-day-year), you might use a [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) that allows you to specify the particulars of the `dateFormat` string:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // if you are using Gregorian calendar regardless of user device settings, uncomment this line
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"                     // note, `yyyy`, not `YYYY`
// formatter.timeZone = .gmt                            // if you want GMT/UTC/Zulu, uncomment this; if you want it in your local timezone, remove this line
guard let date = formatter.date(from: "31-03-2000") else { return }
print(date)
```

Needless to say, if capturing the date in the UI, you would use a [`UIDatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/) in UIKit or [`DatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker/) in SwiftUI, and it avoids all of these date formatter issues.

Comment: Thanks Rob....but where should I insert it in my code?

Comment: Personally, I made them extension of `Rosa`, which means that I can now just use this `age` property on any instance of `Rosa`. I didn’t want to get into those weeds in my original answer (as the salient part was just “use `DateComponentsFormatter`”), but have attempted to be more explicit in my revised answer…